# Passing filters in url to a rest API

Tags: javascript, symfony, typescript, symfony-3.3

I'm building a Ionic App + a Symfony3 Rest Api.
As i need to filter results, I created filters in my api and to pass them i have to use this format :

```
...URL?key=value&key2=value2&array_key[]=array_value1&array_key[]=array_value2
```

So in my Ionic app i created an Object containing all the value i have to pass :

```
let filters : Object;
filters = {
    "key":"value",
    "key2":"value2",
    "array_key":["array_value1","array_value2"]
}
```

Is there a way to transform this object to a string equal to what is waiting my api ?

Answer (score -1):

So I don't know if I'm inventing boiled water doing that but here is what I did :

```
public urlFiltersEncorder(filters: Object):string {
    let url_parts = [];
    for (let filter_key in filters) {
      if(filters[filter_key]  instanceof Array){
        for (let filter_item of filters[filter_key]) {
          url_parts.push(`${filter_key}[]=${encodeURIComponent(filter_item)}`);
        }
      }else{

  url_parts.push(`${filter_key}=${encodeURIComponent(filters[filter_key])}`);
      }
    }
    return '?'+url_parts.join('&');
  }
```

I would be interested to know if there's a better way to do it because I think there's to much code for an usual task...